# Black cherry tomatoes - repot

Tags: tomatoes, containers, repotting

I got black cherry tomatoes growing in pots at the moment.

It's in the middle of spring here and temperatures are between 14 and 20. I am planning to get the tomatoes plants in a bigger container but not sure how big the plant needs to be to put in a bigger pot.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how full of active roots the pot is. A useful skill in gardening with pots is to get experience in knocking the plant out of the pot so that you can see the outside surface of the root ball. Turn the pot with the plant upside down, put spread fingers around the plant base and knock the edge of the pot gently against something solid so that the root ball releases from the pot. You then have the empty pot in one hand and the plant root side up in the other where you can examine how far the roots have explored the available soil. If the root ball tries to fall apart then there are not many roots and the transplant can wait. If there are masses of roots then potting up should be done asap. With some experience you will soon get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's usual to wait until the flowers on the first truss are beginning to open before transferring them to a 9 inch pot (assuming your plants are currently in pots of around 9cm/3.5 inch in size). 
https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/grow-your-own/vegetables/tomatoes

9 inch/23cm pots are the minimum recommended final size, but black cherry tomatoes get pretty tall, usually around 6-8 feet; staking or support is necessary, which means an even larger container will make it easier to provide firm support.